# Nullable Integer instead of int in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I can't find any information about nullable integers in Room.

Can I use `Integer` instead of `int` when I define my entities in Gooogle Room?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested and see that we able use `Integer` to save null integer to database using `Room`